# Visual Studio 2022 IntelliSense

Tags: intellisense

I just started using Visual Studio 2022 and noticed that IntelliSense is not working on some of my projects.

When I start new project it works but on my old ones I can only get

> this message: IntelliSense: 'No additional information available' (See
> 'Configure a C++ project for IntelliSense for further help.)

What I've tried so far:

- removing .vc folder
- checking and unchecking countless of comboboxes

Nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I found it.
In my case I also had

> command-line error language modes specified are incompatible

which was an error but it actually did not stop my projects from compiling.
I just **changed Properties > General > C Language Standard** > to Default
and IntelliSense started to work.